# Carousel is not hidden on load, even though it must be

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css, display

I would greatly appreciate if somebody will help me.

Si I am trying to make  a web page with 3 tabs "London, New York, Shanghai".
On load all is hidden, only "welcome" page is visible.

I Implemented a carousel for images for "London" and it works as intended, but when I tried to copy-and-paste js code for the page and rename all variables for New York, it worked but now
New York Carousel is in **display:block** for some reason, when it has to be in **display:none** by default (in CSS).

And this New Work carousel is on other pages as well.

It has tailwind in it as well but I don't think the problem is in it.

https://github.com/Nikita0x/Nikita0x.github.io/tree/main/cities

I have checked everything meticulously, there should not be any typos, unclosed tags and all cases match. I can't wrap my mind around it, i was trying to copy this - https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp

but it is as if **.mySlides_ny {display:none}**  is ignored

Comment: You have inline styles applying `display: block`

Comment: @Spectric Thank you for reaching out! 
Sorry, this is my first post on Stackoverflow and I am also lost in my own code. 
Yes, I spotted that .dot_ny has display:inline-block, but it did not change anything for me. New York carousel still remains on main page. Could you please point out exactly what I should change? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for providing a link to the repo, that was helpful. The issue may be with this line in your newyork.js file:

```
slides[slideIndex_ny - 1].style.display = "block";
```

Looks like that might be setting display to "block" and overriding the "display:none." I'm not sure what that line is trying to accomplish, but perhaps try commenting it out and see if that changes anything.

Comment: thank you.. Yes, I have tried that as well before your comment, but it does not work as inteded and buttons previous/next are still visible. 
I lack knowledge and experience to fix it, would just rather make a new web with whole pages instead of 1 page with 3 tabs.
But tahnks for everybody who tried to help, we can close this topic now.